# Using queryselectorall with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a line `<div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="176">` in a large html file.

I need to store the value of `product-id` inside a variable, so that I can access it globally.

I'm tring to do it with

```
var var_productid = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-role="priceBox"]')[0].data-product-id;
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.data-product-id` is invalid, `-` is the minus operator for js engine. Since you are using data-attribute, you can access it through `element.dataset.productId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pure javascript you can use the `.getAttribute()` method

```
var var_productid = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-role="priceBox"]')[0].getAttribute('data-product-id');
```

if you want to use jquery, you can do this

`var var_productid = $('div[data-role="priceBox"]').eq(0).attr('data-product-id');`

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to use and retrieve [**data_attributes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in javascript, you need to use `dataset` instead of only data. Also  to get `product-id`, you need to use camel case

```js
var var_productid = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-role="priceBox"]')[0].dataset.productId;
console.log(var_productid)
```

```html
<div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="176"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: In my question, its `data-product-id`. so, the camelcase will be `dataProductId`. Right?

Comment: Nope. It will be `dataset.productId`.dataset property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element, either in HTML or in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

`var productId = $("div[data-role='priceBox']").attr('data-product-id');`

Comment: This doesn't address the need to get the first element

Answer (score 0):

```
dataProductId = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0].getAttribute("data-roduct-id");
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use getAttribute
- No need to use querySelectorAll if you only want the first item found, just use querySelector

Snippet:

```
var productid = document.querySelector('div[data-role="priceBox"]').getAttribute('data-product-id');
```